# Proof of Plancherel's Theorem

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, fourier-analysis, parsevals-identity

> This exercise suggests an alternative proof of Plancherel's Theorem for $L^2(\mathbb{T})$. Given $f \in L^2(\mathbb{T})$, define $f^*(\theta) := \overline{f(-\theta)}$. 
> (a) Prove that for any trigonometric polynomial $f$, it follows from Fourier inversion that $$\Vert f \Vert_2^2 = (f * f^*)(0) = \sum_{-\infty}^\infty |\hat{f}(n)|^2.$$
> (b) Use the above to prove that $f \mapsto \hat{f}$ is an isometry from $L^2(\mathbb{T})$ to $\ell^2(\mathbb{Z})$.

I have shown (a), but am having trouble with (b). I think that the density of trigonometric polynomials will help extend the above formula to all $f$.

Comment: It’s *Plancher**e**l*

Comment: It is called the Parseval identity

Comment: @J.W.Tanner done _/\\_

Comment: I'm not sure if you have anything to do in (b). There is no need to show some identity over the denseness of the polynomials, the convergence of the Fourier series to the original periodic function was already incorporated in (a).